# Laravel - Eloquent: Advanced Wheres

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create something like this using Eloquent. However, I am having trouble with the or clause.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = 1 AND column2 = 2 AND (column3 LIKE $search_term.'%' OR column4 LIKE $search_term.'%') ORDER BY column1;
```

This is what I have:

```
$query = DB::table('table')
        ->where('column1', '=', 1)
        ->where('column2', '=', 2)
        ->orderBy('column1', 'asc'); 

$results = App\Table::where(function ($query) use ($search_term) {
            $query->where('column3', 'like', $search_term.'%');
        })->orwhere(function ($query) use ($search_term) {
            $query->where('column4', 'like', $search_term.'%');
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
$query = DB::table('table')
    ->where('column1', 1)
    ->where('column2', 2)
    ->where(function ($q) use ($search_term) {
        $q->where('column3', 'like', $search_term.'%')
          ->orWhere('column4', 'like', $search_term.'%');
    })
    ->orderBy('column1', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use [`whereRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-exists-clauses)  clause:

```
App\Table::where('column1', 1)
   ->where('column2', 2)
   ->whereRaw("(column3 LIKE $search_term.'%' OR column4 LIKE $search_term.'%')")
   ->orderBy('column1', 'asc');
```

Comment: Avoid using raw query when eloquent itself has a better way to do.

Comment: cant use raw query as search_term comes from user input.

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = App\Table::select('*')
       ->where('column1', 1)
       ->where('column2', 2)
       ->where(function ($query) use ($search_term) {
            $query->where('column3', 'like', $search_term.'%')
                  ->orWhere('column4', 'like', $search_term.'%')
       })
       ->orderBy('column1', 'asc')
       ->get();
```

Comment: This is missing a semi colon on the end of the orWhere line but it did remind me to add get()